# Byobu creating new session on every connection

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, byobu

Every time I connect to my Ubuntu 17.10 machine with byobu-enable turned on, I get a new "session" rather than it reusing my existing sessions.

On connect:

```
Byobu sessions...

  1. tmux: foo: 3 windows (created Sun Jan 28 10:23:59 2018) [204x53] (group foo)
  2. tmux: ba: 1 windows (created Sun Jan 28 10:24:16 2018) [204x53]
  3. Create a new Byobu session (tmux)
  4. Run a shell without Byobu (/bin/bash)
```

Upon selecting one, say (1), I am dumped to a byobu session named e.g. _foo-20462

```
$ byobu list-session
_foo-20462: 4 windows (created Sun Jan 28 10:42:20 2018) [204x53] (group foo)
foo: 4 windows (created Sun Jan 28 10:23:59 2018) [204x53] (group foo)
bar: 1 windows (created Sun Jan 28 10:24:16 2018) [204x53]
```

The odd thing is that _foo-20462 appears to be an exact replica of the "foo" session. The only way I can figure out to kill these is `byobu kill-session -t _foo-20462`, but I figure there must be a way to disable this behavior, as it was not the same in prior versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: fixed byobu 5.125. https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/commit/755c0e9f28b3f8ee57d9c7fc166f0bcbe96577db
https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/c4136ebfe970c31a785fb87468fa08ab7fd7039e/debian/changelog#L11

Comment: Thank you @gs1! My use case is to have multiple users connect to an SSH server independently and work in separate tabs. Having a separate session for each client is a desirable feature, not a bug. Restore old behavior with `touch ~/.byobu/.reuse-session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a fix. I created an issue about this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1750430

I put on my detective hat and managed to fix it.

---

TL;DR - Either call `tmux` directly or revert a change in Byobu's `select-session.py`.

---

Running a plain `tmux` command attaches to the first session, so this is probably the easiest "fix" for this (the oddly named sessions are only created with the `tmux` backend, not with `screen`).

---

However, you can fix this for Byobu, too.

`man byobu` revealed that the part of Byobu that's responsible for selecting the session is `byobu-select-session`.

`which byobu-select-session` directed me to `/usr/bin/byobu-select-session`, which in turn calls `/usr/libexec/byobu/include/select-session.py`. These paths may be different for you (I'm on Fedora).

The line in `select-session.py` that creates and names the session is this one (in the function `attach_session()`):

```
os.execvp("tmux", ["tmux", "-2", "new-session", "-t", session_name, "-s", "_%s-%i" % (session_name, os.getpid())])
```

So, Byobu intentionally creates a session named `_%s-%i`, where `%s` is the session name and `%i` is the PID.

Looking into the Git blame for the line shows this commit:
https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/commit/c0050ac51ee8accc3eb35862483bc40b19e3c269

Reverting the line fixes the issue:

```
os.execvp("tmux", ["tmux", "-2", "attach", "-t", session_name])
```

...but probably also removes support for "tmux grouped sessions", but I'm not entirely certain what they're used for, and I can live without them.

Comment: Thanks, I had fixed this a similar way and answered this other question without remembering to update this one! https://superuser.com/questions/1282214/reattaching-byobu-session-creates-group-0/1291236?noredirect=1#comment1912146_1291236.  It's not clear to me whether attach or new-session -A is the correct behavior here, but reverting the commit is a pretty strong signal it should be attach. :)